# Toggle Switch doesn't work on safari and chrome but works in Firefox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I copy pasted the codes from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp but after testing the code I noticed that it doesn't work on Chrome and Safari (they're the latest versions) on Ubuntu/Mac/iOS. Here is the css code:

```
 /* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Also, by not working  I mean that when I switch the checkbox it doesn't change its color or actually it doesn't switch at all but the linked Js function gets called successfully.

Comment: Change the pseudo-classes to the new syntax -- single colon  `:before` to double colon `::before`

Comment: @zer00ne Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste properly then. It all works for me on my latest chrome. What is the question?